# How to translate :"something something something, PERIOD."

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to translate the following sentence:

> And something that is not consensual is not ethical, **period**.

But this period here bothers me. So far I'm using "ja" like this:

> Kaj io kiu ne estas konsenta, ne **ja** estas etika.

Can I put the ja at the end for more emphasis?:

> Kaj sekso kiu ne estas konsenta, ne estas etika **ja**.

Is there a stronger way to convey the idea?

Comment: Uzi _ja_ estas tute trafa solvo. Sed vi devas meti ĝin **antaŭ** la _ne_. Ekzemple: "tio ja ne estas etika".

Comment: Dankon kora. Vi multe helpis min.

Answer (score 2):

**Period** tutigas la ideon kaj samtempe celas nuligi la eblon diskuti aŭ pludiskuti. La enhavo estas ia verdikto kaj oni povas emfazi tion ŝajnigante diktaĵon, per aldono de la frazo *[fina punkto](http://vortaro.net/#punkto)* aŭ la vorto *punkto*, ekzemple:

```
la Akademio decidis—punkto! (ekzemplo en PIV, pural aliaj en Tekstaro)
```

aŭ

```
Io nekonsenta ne estas ektika. Fina punkto.
```

Dum interparolado mi tamen uzus *(kaj) jen.*:

```
Io nekonsenta ne estas etika, kaj jen.
```

Comment: Multajn dankojn.

Thank you for your answer. After your answer I searched for it and found "**punkto fino**" as well. Is there a difference in nuance in these expressions?

Comment: _punkto fino_ sounds weird, with the two nouns right by each other. Maybe _punkto, fino_ or even _finpunkto_.

Comment: I’ve heard “punktofino” (as one word) before and I think it’s good. With the words this way round it is like “fino de la punkto”, ie, the point has now finished and you can’t discuss it anymore. The other way around “fina punkto” sounds odd to me, as if that is the last point in a list of points.

Comment: _punkto fina_ and _fina punkto_ ([the form PIV uses](http://vortaro.net/#punkto)) mean the same thing, and it is exactly that, the last period (there could eventually be others) in a paragraph. When people dictate, you have periods that end sentences and periods that end paragraphs (that's _fina punkto_, the others are _punkto_). _Punktofino_ in Esperanto is not a period, but an **ending**, just as _lignotablo_ is a table and not wood (more at [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/antauelementoj.html)). I don't know if _Punktofino_ (_punkta fino_) makes sense in this situation.

Comment: “Punktofino” makes sense if you mean “punkto” as a part of a conversation, not the symbol, like in the 7th definition from PIV: “speciala temo, kiun oni atentas”. In that case “punktofino” is the end of the point, la fino de la temo.

Answer (score 0):

The usual expression is : io, io, io, punkto fino.

> Kaj io kiu ne estas konsenta, ne ja estas etika.

make that: kaj io kio ne estas konsenta, ja ne estas etika

> Can I put the ja at the end for more emphasis?:

```
Kaj sekso kiu ne estas konsenta, ne estas etika ja.
```

No. "ja" is a german word that English has no equivalent of, and in Esperanto it has the meaning that is not the opposite of no/ne. (even though some do use it as the opposite of not)

sekso=sexe, not sex.